# How can you give an error code for a username and password in a C# Xaml form with MySql if they don't match your database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been able to connect to my database, but when I try to create an error by writing in the wrong username or password nothing pops up(for example "Wrong Password Entered").  Also, I have tried to prepare statements for the user text boxes with the @username, but I am not sure if this really stops SQL injection with C#.

```
//XAml
    <TextBox x:Name="textUser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="201,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="txt_passwordBox" Margin="201,152,196,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" KeyDown="txt_passwordBox_KeyDown" PasswordChar="$"/>


//C# code

    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

    //click login button
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        if (textUser.Text != "" & txt_passwordBox.Password != "")
            {
                server = "54.12.23.11";
                database = "databasetest";
                uid = "username";
                password = "password";
                string connectionString;
                connectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "user=" + uid+ ";" + "database=" + database + ";port=3306;" + "password=" + password + ";";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {

                conn.Open();//connect to mysql

                string sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user=@username and pass=@password";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

                string username1 = textUser.Text;
                string password1 = txt_passwordBox.Password;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password1);

                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {



                    if (Convert.ToString(rdr["password"]) != password1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong password");
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToString(rdr["username"]) != username1)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username");
                    }
                    else if ((Convert.ToString(rdr["username"]) != username1) && (Convert.ToString(rdr["password"]) != password1))
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username or Password");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //textError.Text = (rdr["username"] + " --- " + rdr["password"]);
                        loggedinwindowpumpkin window = new loggedinwindowpumpkin();
                        this.Close();
                        window.ShowDialog();
                        // }
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting.... Check Network Settings, Close and try again");
                // MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Wrong User or Password");
            }

            conn.Close();
            //MessageBox.Show("Connected to Database.");
        }
    }//end button_Click
```

Comment: The title doesn't seems to fit your question

Comment: That was odd, I revised it.

Comment: It is still not precise. If I understood your problem you want to prevent a sql injection.

Comment: So with this code if I don't put in the right username or password it doesn't give me an error message for example "Wrong password".  I wasn't sure if these prepared statements (for example @username) really help that much for sql injection.

Comment: You get a *null* result from your query. No exception is thrown also. You should handle the case - your case - if nothings comes back from reader, pass and/or user are invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in my Comment, you're getting no results back.

This should do the trick:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();//connect to mysql

                    string sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user=@username and pass=@password";
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {

                        string username1 = textUser.Text;
                        string password1 = txt_passwordBox.Password;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username1);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password1);

                        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (!rdr.HasRows)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username or Password");
                                return;
                            }
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {

                                if (Convert.ToString(rdr["password"]) != password1)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong password");
                                }
                                else if (Convert.ToString(rdr["username"]) != username1)
                                {

                                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username");
                                }
                                else if ((Convert.ToString(rdr["username"]) != username1) && (Convert.ToString(rdr["password"]) != password1))
                                {

                                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username or Password");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //textError.Text = (rdr["username"] + " --- " + rdr["password"]);
                                    loggedinwindowpumpkin window = new loggedinwindowpumpkin();
                                    this.Close();
                                    window.ShowDialog();
                                    // }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting.... Check Network Settings, Close and try again");
                    // MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Wrong User or Password");
                }
            }
```

Comment: On this one I could just get rid of the if, else if's correct? (for the rdr["password"] etc.)

Comment: Correct. If theres no record You dont have to check

Answer (score 0):

Afaik if you really want to secure your query you have to pass the data type of the parameter. Otherwise it is just a replacement of the placeholder in your query.

```
string sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user=@username and pass=@password";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

string username1 = textUser.Text;
string password1 = txt_passwordBox.Password;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", password1));
```

The default data type of an instance of the SqlParameter class is DbType.NVarChar. If you want to specify a other data type you have to do it this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", DbType.NVarChar){Value = username1});
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but this is how I learned to do it.

Comment: Well @Sol you edited your title and question for the third time in a row. Therefore my answer doesn't fits any more to your question nor title.

Comment: I realized that simple is better.  So I tried to condense it to not be confusing.

Comment: MySQL must not have NVarChar.  It didn't have it as an option

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: I know a MySQL database has it built in, but C# gives an error on it and the available values don't have it.  They just list things like String, Int32, etc.  I changed the initial SqlParameter to MySqlParameter to work with MySQL.  This may be only a MS SQL database command.

Comment: VarChar is of course not an data type in C#. It is an enum indicating the data type for the query. Look at my second example.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are selecting user and pass where user = input and pass = input, and then you do `while(rdr.read())`. So let's say you have table:

```
|User | PW|
|user1| 1 |
|user2| 2 |
|user3| 3 |
```

So now, if i put `Username: user1` and `Password: 2` it will try to select from database where `user = user1 and password = 2`, and in this table i do not have that so it will not enter `while(rdr.read())` so it will just skip that and you do not do anything if it doesn't read.

I would recommend you to select `username, password where user = inputed user` and then you check if selected password = inputed password

So it would go something like this:

```
string sqlcommand = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user=@username";

//do all code for command, con and parameters

while (rdr.Read())
{
    //store username and password
}
if(storedPassword == inputedPassword)
{
    loggedinwindowpumpkin window = new loggedinwindowpumpkin();
                    this.Close();
                    window.ShowDialog();
}
else
{
    //wrong password message
}
```

Also you can check if reader read username, and if not to display message for unknown user.

Comment: Could you guide me on the "//store username and password" in the reader part some more thanks.